# Rename misspelled tag [mdboostrap] -> [mdbootstrap]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Per [How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87437/209031)

There's a typo in [mdboostrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mdboostrap) which should be spelled `mdbootstrap` with a **t**

Comment: It is a Boost Rap ....